# Pointers in C while using array and swap function

Tags: c, mergesort

I had a doubt in using pointers
For example I made this swapping program and to swap so i have to use pointers in order to maintain same address where swapping is happening

```
#include<stdio.h>
int swap(int *x,int *y);  //swapping function
int main()
{
int a,b;
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
printf("A->%d,B->%d\n",a,b); //print original array
swap(&a,&b);   //pass by reference
printf("A->%d,B->%d\n",a,b);  //print sorted array
}

int swap(int *x,int *y)
{
int temp;    // Swapping
temp =*x;
*x=*y;
*y=temp;
}
```

Then I wrote a program for merge sort. Here I just passed the value (pass by value) in the funtions without using pointers but when I print the sorted array in the main function it is sorted.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void merge(int a[],int start,int mid,int end);  //Sorting and merging lists
void mergesort(int a[],int start,int end);   //Dividing the list

int main()
{
int size,i;
scanf("%d",&size);
int arr[size];
for(i=0;i<size;i++)  //Input array
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
printf("Array is: ");

for(i=0;i<size;i++)      
{
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);   //print original array
}
printf("\n");

mergesort(arr,0,size-1);   //Mergesort call-pass by value

printf("Sorted Array is: ");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
printf("%d ",arr[i]);    //print sorted array
}
printf("\n");
}


void mergesort(int a[],int start,int end)
{
int mid;
if(start<end)
{
 mid=(start+end)/2;           //calculating mid and dividing array recursively
 mergesort(a,start,mid);
 mergesort(a,mid+1,end);
 merge(a,start,mid+1,end);
}
}



void merge(int a[],int start,int mid,int end)
{
int b[end];  //auxillary array
int i;
int p=start,q=mid,k=start;
while((p<mid) && (q<=end))     //comparing both list 
{
  if(a[p]<=a[q])        
  {
    b[k++]=a[p++];
  }
  else
  {
    b[k++]=a[q++];
  }
 }
 while(p<mid)    //adding remaing items to auxillary array
 {
  b[k++]=a[p++];
 }
 while(q<=end)   //adding remaing items to auxillary array
 {
  b[k++]=a[q++];
 }
 for(i=start;i<k;i++)   //copying items from auxillary array to original array
 {
  a[i]=b[i];
 }
}
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You should use `void` instead of `int` for `int_swap`, because it isn't actually returning anything.

Comment: int arr[size]; is an invalid statement.

Comment: It would have been invalid if I had not scanned size from the user

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly pass arrays by value in C (best you can do is wrap a fixed-size array in a struct). In a parameter list `int a[]` is exactly equivalent to `int *a`.

So you are using pointers and that's why the array is sorted.

Comment: thnx i didt know that

Answer (score 1):

In C and similar languages the first array dimension of a function parameter is rewriten as a pointer. So your interfaces

```
void merge(int a[],int start,int mid,int end);
void mergesort(int a[],int start,int end);
```

are exactly the same as

```
void merge(int* a,int start,int mid,int end);
void mergesort(int* a,int start,int end);
```

So actually for arrays, you always pass an address to your function.

Comment: thnx i didt know that

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say:

> Here I just passed the value (pass by value) in the funtions without using pointers.

because, when you use

```
mergesort(int a[],int start,int end)
merge(int a[],int start,int mid,int end)
```

Then `a[]` is as same as when you use `*a`. It is using the pointer way.

Comment: thnx i didt know that

Comment: Keep moving forward!

Comment: Please learn how to use Markdown. It'll improve your posts considerably. For example, don't use `<br>` to make newlines; instead, put two newlines where you want a paragraph break, and indent by four spaces to make a code block.

Comment: Your advices are really helpful. I'll learn how to use Markdown right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And by the way, could you tell me know where I can learn how to use Markdown, plz?